# $a_n$ be a sequence in [0,1]. what about f($a_n$)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

consider a strictly increasing function f. let $a_n$ be a sequence in [0,1]. which of following is true about f($a_n$)?

1. f($a_n$)  is bounded
2. f($a_n$)  is convergent
3. f($a_n$)  is bounded but not convergent
4. f($a_n$)  is unbounded

my attempt:

let f=x, so f($a_n$)=$a_n$. since nothing can be surely said about an except that it is bounded. so f($a_n$) is bounded. plz give your suggestion

Comment: What do *you* think?

Comment: If you really try I'm sure you will be able to prove that it is bounded by using the two pieces of information that you are given: 1) $f$ is stricktly increasing 2) $a_n$ is contained in a bounded interval ($[0,1]$).

Comment: so answer is option 1?

Comment: Does it say something about the domain of $f$?

Comment: no, only that it is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are dealing with a strictly increasing function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ we conclude that $f(0)\leq f(a_n)\leq f(1)$ for each $n$.

This tells us that the sequence $(f(a_n))_n$ is a bounded sequence.

The sequence can be convergent, but that is not necessary. E.g. let $f$ be prescribed by $x\mapsto x$. Then $f(a_n)=a_n$ and the sequence $(f(a_n))_n$ iff sequence $(a_n)_n$ is convergent.